# Completed CakePHP Tutorial code

Tags: cakephp, acl

I have been trying to learn CakePHP's ACL stuff recently but keep getting confused, does anyone have a completed version i.e. the source and database for the ACL tutorial at the Cookbook here: http://book.cakephp.org/view/1543/Simple-Acl-controlled-Application

Would much appreciate it, as I'd love to have a play with a working solution on my localhost.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mark Story did a great tutorial here:

http://mark-story.com/posts/view/auth-and-acl-an-end-to-end-tutorial-pt-1

and here:

http://mark-story.com/posts/view/auth-and-acl-an-end-to-end-tutorial-pt-2

The Cake Manual version is based on this, but I found it much easier to follow for some reason. What particular problems are you running into?

Comment: The whole Bake thing is confusing to me :/

Comment: Just take it slow, with a coffee or a beer, and work through it without missing anything. It's okay to copy and paste code - you're learning the principle of the thing here, not wearing out your fingertips. It will, eventually, click. For what it's worth, the only thing I usually use bake for is ACL. The rest I hand code - much more control that way.

Comment: doing the tutorial a few times is also ok. as for bake, i use it only to generate fixtures for test cases.

Comment: The problem is the tutorial requires the use of bake to generate all the code but there are no decent up-to-date tutorials on how to use Bake. Plus a lot of the acl stuff isn't explained very well e.g. what is that install function for? Do I seriously need to manually run a function to update the acl stuff eveytime something changes?

Comment: Although I just noticed that Mark added the source to the end of his tutorial so I'm going to have a play around with it.